# Is it possible to create a singleton WCF that is maintaining memory a per-user-session only?

Tags: c#, wcf, singleton

I wanted to create a WCF that employs a singleton pattern but the service itself would not share the same memory as other users?

my WCF ServiceBehavior currently is setup to this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Unfortunately, there are instances that data is mixed up to two different users (which is a bad thing).

I could do a PerCall, but i would modify a whole lot of code :(
Just hoping there is still chance for my code.

Comment: If data is getting mixed up between different users, I'd think the service would need to be modified to some degree as it sounds to me like a (potentially) serious desing flaw crept in somewhere.  I don't think there's an "easy" fix in this case (of course, I don't know the details of your situation, so maybe there is).

Comment: thanks for the response. Generally, would a singleton WCF share some private field objects in memory with other users accessing the service?

Comment: Since it's a singleton, every user is going to access the same object, so they'll be hitting the same data unless the service is storing that data in some manner that allows it to differentiate between the users.  The real question I think is why are you using a singleton?  I've implemented 7 or so services (and helped with 2 or 3 more) over the last 18 months, and in all that time I only had reason to do one as a singleton.

Comment: would storing data in a Session object change it, then? instead of storing the value in memory, how about a session variable since it would recognize a user uniquely?

Comment: I haven't had occasion to use Session with WCF services.  There might be an issue if there's only one Session object for the WCF Service (since it's a singleton) - I don't know off the top of my head if that's the case, but I suspect it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton = any private field in the class are shared among all calls to the class. If you want to have singleton service but separate data for each user you must store the data elsewhere (not in the service instance) - for example in the database and load them for every user's call.

Singleton service should be used in very rare cases. Most of the time usage of singleton service only means wrong architecture.

Comment: I was trying to convert a driver code to a web service, and needed to know this. Thanks for the info. BTW, many drivers are written in singleton pattern don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are suffering from state full services.
An easy way to spot them is to just look at your class definition and if you find member variables in there  , ask your self do you really need them being member.

if no just remove them

if yes try work out if you can put them cache(static, dynamic)

if cant put them in cache then try fetching them from your db.

here is what i followed from years of experience

1) Services should as stateless as possible. Or just think they are stateless.

2) For performance they can maintain two types of cache

a) static cache ( cache which is read only and stays same as long as set of services are serving)
                mostly done during start of services. eg your workflow cache

b) Dynamic cache ( which can be refreshed time to time ) eg Authorisation cache